# Ruby on Rails with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, openshift

I have a rails app with mongoid where I am trying to insert a document to the collection using the following code. It works perfectly well in my dev environment where I have straight up mongo, with rails. However in live(where I dont have much control) it runs in phusion passenger. I am getting the following error in live:

```
TypeError (can't convert nil into String):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:26:in `create'
```

Following is my code for the controller:

```
@users2 = User.new("title" => "sample title");
@users2.save
```

following is my code in model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String
  field :category, :type => String
```

To be clear I am using openshift app where I have deployed mongo with rails.
any idea guys?

Comment: its getting the nill value can you please add the controller as well

Answer (score 0):

if it giving to this line
@users2 = User.new("title" => "sample title");
then 
@users2 = User.new("title" => "sample title".to_s);

let me know please

Answer (score 0):

Change the line from @users2 = User.new("title" => "sample title") to @users2 = User.new(:title => "sample title"). Are you line no 26 is above line? What version of mongoid you are using?